# Do I need a transit visa to pass through YYZ if returning from YUL?

Tags: transit-visas

I am an Indian national who would be returning from YUL (Montreal), passing through YYZ (Toronto). Flight route: YUL-YYZ-CDG-BOM. Will I need a transit visa to pass through YYZ? Also, I will have a layover of around 2 hours 30 minutes at YYZ. Is it sufficient?

I am traveling internationally for the first time. Sorry if I asked something obvious! Thanks!

Comment: To answer your other question: 2h30m is an ample amount of time for a Canada-to-international layover at YYZ.  (The worst layovers at YYZ tend to be Canada-to-US or vice versa, and even then I wouldn't worry about a layover of that length.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a transit visa in Toronto, coming from Montréal: you're still in Canada and haven't left the country. So you needn't worry about that.

However, you might need a transit visa in CDG. If your Canadian visa is still valid, you won't, but if it expires when you leave Canada, you'll need a Schengen transit visa.

Comment: Our canonical answer that the just-used Canadian visa exempts the OP from the need for an airside transit visa at CDG. (This rule holds only for departures from Canada, US, several other high-economic countries.) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area